"Failed to get block: <hash>" error from electrum-client
I've installed bitcoin node and electrs server on VPS. I write nodejs script to listen new transaction from specific addrs and I get this error when I use Electrum protocol method blockchain.scripthash.subscribe to subscribe scripthash. Then I use electrumClient.subscribe.on event to listen new tx. But I always get this error
Failed to get block: 0000000000000000000000b71ed0d9bec536d4fbbfa4da8dece0edb25324d11db0
This block hash has 66 characters instead of 64 characters. Anyone get this error?
enter image description here
I also delete electrs_db folder and sync data again but it doesn't help.
I checked electrs log but there is no error. Bitcoin node and Electrs server work fine.
const ElectrumClient = require('electrum-client');
const electrumClient = new ElectrumClient(ELECTRUM_PORT, ELECTRUM_HOST, PROTOCOL);
electrumClient.connect();

const scriptHash = 'xxxxxx';
electrumClient.blockchainScripthash_subscribe(scriptHash).then((scriptHash) => {              
    console.log(`Subscribed to updates for scripthash: ${scriptHash}`);
});

electrumClient.subscribe.on('blockchain.scripthash.subscribe', async (data) => {
    const [scripthash, status] = data;
    //receive a notification when the status of the script hash changes.
    //do something here....
});

The electrum connection is closed when this error happens.
How could I solve this problem or ignore an error?
